# PHPExcel showing garbage in main page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdf, phpexcel

I need to generate a PDF file with some information i get from a database, i'm using PHPExcel in order to do this, but here is the thing, when i click the button `report` so i get all the information and put it into the PDF, i get a lot of "garbage" in my page, this garbage it's like when you try to open a PDF with notepad and it just shows random symbols.

Here is how i do it

I'm using an `$.ajax` call to get all the information displayed into a form:

```
$.ajax({
    // gets all the information and puts them into the form and several tables
});
```

Then i add an event handler to the button `report`  so that i send the request id to a php script which will gather the necessary information to fill the report

```
report.on('click',function(){       
    $.ajax({
        url  : '../../php/reports/requestReport.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : {'idRequest' : id },
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error : function(response){
            if(response.responseText != undefined)
                $('body').append(response.responseText);            
            console.warn(response);
        }
    }); 
});
```

And on my php file i have something like this:

```
<?php
    require '../functions.php';
    require '../classes/PHPExcel.php';

    if(isset($_POST['idRequest']))
        $idRequest = $_POST['idRequest'];
    else{
        $idRequest = false;
        echo json_encode(array("ExitCode"=>1,"Message"=>"idRequest Not Received","Location"=>"requestReport.php"));
    }


if($idRequest){
try{
    // get all the data
    // save the request and send it to the report
    $excel = new PHPExcel();
    //Initializing
    $excel->getProperties()->setCreator("TTMS")
                         ->setLastModifiedBy("TTMS")
                         ->setTitle("Request update $idRequest");

    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('C1', 'Request For Q.A. / Q.C. / Testing');

    // Rename worksheet
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("$idRequest");


    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (PDF)
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Update_Request_'.$idRequest.'.pdf"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'PDF');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
} catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo json_encode(array("ExitCode"=>2,"Message"=>$ex->getMessage(),"Location"=>"requestReport.php PDOException"));
}
```

So long story short i get garbage on the page where the form is. I think it has something to do with the fact that i'm doing this via `ajax` but i need to do this so the `echo`'s i have to report the errors in my code.

Comment: I'm confused. You're generating an Excel spreadsheet, but naming it as a PDF? A PDF is not, never has been, and never will be an Excel spreadsheet, so no wonder you're getting out garbage. That's like renaming a .jpg image to "cutekittens.txt" and expecting Notepad to be to able to display the image.

Comment: PHPExcel allows me to create a excel file but at the end just save it as a PDF, most of this i just copied from a tutorial in PHPExcel's documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing the PDF output inside an existing HTML page

```
$('body').append(response.responseText);
```

The browser assumes everything displayed in an HTML page is HTML markup, not a stream of binary data.

Direct the output to a new browser window if success.

Comment: How can i open another window from javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Write all the output to an HTML file, then use wkhtmltopdf -> http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ to convert it to PDF.  It works awesome!

Here is code you would use to create your html file:

```
if (!$handle = fopen('/path/to/folder/your_file.html', 'w')) {
     die("Cannot open file for write");
}

$data_string = "<html><body></body></html>"; //all your html output goes here, formatted correctly, etc

// Write somecontent to our opened file.
if (fwrite($handle, $data_string) === FALSE) {
    die("Cannot write to file");
}
```

Then once that is successful you convert it to PDF, then remove the old html file

```
   // convert to PDF
    $output = shell_exec('wkhtmltopdf --page-size Letter /path/to/folder/your_file.html /path/to/folder/your_file.pdf');
    if (strpos($output,'Error') == false){
        $output = shell_exec('rm /path/to/folder/your_file.html');
    }else{
        die("error creating pdf, please contact IT administrator.");
    }
```

Now you have the PDF sitting in the location -> `/path/to/folder/your_file.pdf` which you can make the user download.

Comment: I see this uses the webkit engine, i have to make sure this work 100% with firefox, wouldn't it  cause a problem ?

Comment: besides i think forcing my users to use the command line wouldn't be viable

Comment: this is all server-side.  You output to an html file on your web server (not on client machine), then you use PHP to convert the HTML file to PDF.  Then make the client download the PDF.  I will update my answer with an example script.

Comment: Oh ok got it, but it still is a windows environment in here - EDIT nevermind i see they got windows installers, going to check it out a little